# How to transform a variable to bucketed variable which tells us which bucket/range it lies to in pytorch

Tags: numpy, pytorch, regression

I have a variable `a = [0.129, 0.369, 0.758, 0.012, 0.925]`. I want to transform this variable into a bucketed variable. What I mean by this is explained below.

`min_bucket_value, max_bucket_value = 0, 1` (Can be anything, for example, 0 to 800, but the min value is always going to be 0)

`num_divisions = 10` (For this example I've taken 10, but it can be higher as well, like 80 divisions instead of 10)

Bucket/division ranges are as shown below.

```
0 - 0.1 -> 0
0.1 - 0.2 -> 1
0.2 - 0.3 -> 2
0.3 - 0.4 -> 3
0.4 - 0.5 -> 4
0.5 - 0.6 -> 5
0.6 - 0.7 -> 6
0.7 - 0.8 -> 7
0.8 - 0.9 -> 8
0.9 - 1.0 -> 9
```

so, `transformed_a = [1, 3, 7, 0, 9]`

So it's like I divide `min_bucket_value, max_bucket_value` in `num_divisions`  different ranges/buckets and then transform original `a` to tell which bucket it lies in

I've tried creating `torch.linspace(min_bucket_value, max_bucket_value, num_divisions)`, but not sure how to move forward and map it to a range so that I can get the bucket index to which it belongs to

Can you guys please help

**EDIT**

There's an extension to this problem.

Let's say that we've got `a = [127, 362, 799]` and I want to create two buckets. One is a coarse bucket, so `a_transform = [12, 36, 89]`, but what if I want a fine bucket as well so that my second transformation becomes `a_fine_transform = [7, 2, 9]`.

Sub-range index within the range. Basically, coarse division has 80 buckets (giving 127 in 12th bucket) and then the fine bucket which has 10 divisions which tells us that 127 lies in 12th coarse bucket and 7th fine bucket

`a` can be in float as well. eg, `a = [127.36, 362.456, 789.646]`.

so `a_coarse_transform = [12, 36, 78]` & `a_fine_transform = [7, 2, 6]`

where `min_bucket_value, max_bucket_value, num_coarse_divisions, num_fine_divisions  = 0, 1, 80, 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For torch tensor, you can simply use the following code (part of the answer from Bob and partly different to work it will tensor since numpy won't work unless and until you call .cpu() method on the tensor, which I'm not sure is the right thing to do)

So instead to this,

```
a1 = (a - min_bucket_value) / (max_bucket_value - min_bucket_value)

a_coarse_transform, r = ((a1 * coarse_divisions)//1).type(torch.long), (a1 * coarse_divisions)%1
a_fine_transform, r = ((r * fine_divisions)//1).type(torch.long), (r * fine_divisions)%1
```

Answer (score 1):

For equally spaced buckets you can do it constant time with respect to the number of buckets, width, or location.

Use an affine map to place the values from the range (min_bucket_value, max_bucket_value) to the
range `0 < a1 < 1`

```
a1 = (a - min_bucket_value) / (max_bucket_value - min_bucket_value)
```

Get the index of the divisions

```
b = (a1 * num_divisions).astype(torch.long)
```

With this method if you have elements outside the bucket range in `a` you will have indices outside the range `0:num_divisions`.

---

If you want to apply multiple levels of partitioning

```
a_coarse_transform, r = numpy.divmod(a1 * coarse_divisions, 1)
a_fine_transform, r = numpy.divmod(r * fine_divisions, 1)
```

If you wanted one more level you could simply apply `divmod` to `r` again, specifying the number of divisions

Comment: There's an extension to this problem, can you help me there. let's say that we've got ```a = [121, 362, 799]``` and I want to create two buckets, one is coarse bucket, for which you already provided the solution, so ```a_transform = [12, 36, 89], but what if I want a fine bucket as well so that my second transformation becomes ```a_fine_transform = [1, 2, 9]```, basically sub range index withing the range. basically coarse division has 80 buckets (giving 127 in 12th bucket) and then the fine bucket which has 10 divisions which tells us that 127 lies in 12th coarse bucket and 7th fine bucket

Comment: ```a``` can be in float as well. eg, ```a = [127.36, 362.456, 789.646]```, so ```a_coarse_transform = [12, 36, 78]``` & ```a_fine_transform = [7, 2, 6]```, where ```min_bucket_value, max_bucket_value, num_coarse_divisions, num_fine_ divisions  = 0, 1, 80, 10```

Comment: just apply the same procedure updating `min_bucket_value`, `max_bucket_value` and `num_divisions`, in your example `min_bucket_value=120`, `max_bucket_value=30`, `num_divisions=10`.

Comment: Yes, we can manually assign new ```min_bucket_value``` and ```max_bucket_value``` manually. But how do you update this for all 3 elements of ```a``` automatically via algo

Comment: Appended this to the answer.

Comment: I don't think divmod works with pytorch tensor

Comment: Nevermind, used numpy.divmod. It works. Thanks for the help. You can update your answer with numpy